# How to run an SQL query via VBA where the query is stored in an Excel cell?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to run an SQL query via VBA where the query is stored in an Excel cell. The images show the VBA code, which works perfectly as long as the query dont contain aggregated functions with a group by clause at the end. The last part of the codes that works refer to "mydate" which is a defined variable in my Excel spreadsheet, and the query will then run for that date via "where value_date=    .  The string in VBA is defined as this: *Src = Worksheets("Cash-renter oversikt").Range("AX2").Value & "'" & myDate & "'"*.

[Picture of the VBA code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJKBZ.png)

When i try to write a query with aggregated functions and include a group by clause at the end of the query, which is stored in the excel cell, i get an error message: "incorrect syntax near the keyword group". My theory is that VBA is only able to read the query up until the "where value_date=    and the reference to "mydate". How can i change the VBA code so that is able to read the group by clause in the sql query?

[Picture of the SQL query stored in Excel cell AX2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koOgD.png)

Comment: Please do not post pictures. Copy/paste actual code. As an aside, you may want to consider that running arbitrary SQL from a human editable source is an security risk. Have you tested that you are running the SQL that you think you are? If your variable is not applied or has incorrect quoting you'll get that error

Comment: the value of mydate is appended to the end of the string so would be after the group by. 

You need to manipulate the query string to include that date.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the GROUP BY line in a separate cell so you can append it after myDate. For example using AY2.

```vb
With Worksheets("Cash-renter oversikt")
    Src = .Range("AX2").Value & "'" & myDate & "' " & .Range("AY2").Value
End With
```